# Failing tests for python package statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've downloaded the Python package statsmodels (using pip) and run the tests, and found several were failing out of the gate. The test command is

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> sm.test()
```

There are two errors and one failure:

```
=====================================================================
ERROR: statsmodels.sandbox.panel.test_sandwich.test_cov_cluster_2groups
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/sandbox/panel/test_sandwich.py", line 30, in test_cov_cluster_2groups
    cov01, covg, covt = sw.cov_cluster_2groups(res, group, group2=time)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/sandbox/panel/sandwich_covariance.py", line 555, in cov_cluster_2groups
    group_intersection = Group(group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/grouputils.py", line 182, in __init__
    uni, uni_idx, uni_inv = combine_indices(group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/grouputils.py", line 60, in combine_indices
    return_inverse=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 178, in unique
perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort')
TypeError: requested sort not available for type

======================================================================
ERROR: statsmodels.tsa.base.tests.test_datetools.test_infer_freq
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tests/test_datetools.py", line 63, in test_infer_freq
    npt.assert_string_equal(_infer_freq(b), 'B')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/datetools.py", line 234, in _infer_freq
    elif delta >= timedelta(28*nobs) and delta <= timedelta(31*nobs):
TypeError: ufunc 'greater_equal' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_monotone_fn_inverter (statsmodels.distributions.tests.test_ecdf.TestDistributions)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/distributions/tests/test_ecdf.py", line 41, in test_monotone_fn_inverter
    npt.assert_array_equal(f.y, x[::1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 707, in assert_array_equal
    verbose=verbose, header='Arrays are not equal')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 636, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array([ 15.,  14.,  13.,  12.,  11.,  10.,   9.,   8.,   7.,   6.])
 y: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1454 tests in 67.411s
```

Other possibly helpful information:

- `statsmodel v0.4.0` (also tried `v0.5.0`)
- `numpy v1.6.2`
- `scipy v0.10.1`
- all of these packages were pip'd
- `python v2.7.3` installed on Mac OSX 10.8 using homebrew `brew install python` (i.e. not OSX native python).
- I pip'd a few other packages, too: `joblib v0.6.4`, `nose v1.1.2`, and `patsy v0.1.0`. `Nose` was required for testing, and `patsy` is needed to `import statsmodels.api`. The test suite also complained that `joblib` was needed for running in parallel.

I'm not sure of what to make of the first two errors, and the failure looks a bit weird, kind of like an implementation change or something...but I suspect that the statsmodels guys/gals ran their tests before they called it a day :) So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the latest release http://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels/0.4.3

As far as I remember, all these errors are fixed.

The first error is a change in the behavior of numpy in 1.6.2.

I think, the second is related to the change in datetime handling with the transition to using the new numpy dtypes in newer pandas versions.

The last was a mistake in the test.

The mailing list or issue tracker might be better places to report these test failures:
http://groups.google.com/group/pystatsmodels 
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues